# I trying to add titles, heading, description to the output from a list. I only get the 1st letter of the 4th item on my List

Tags: python, html

I'm working on generating a HTML Page with Python for an assignment. I have a list of one title, headings, & description. I trying to create a 'for' loop to take each list and populate just my divs tags many times. I having a hard time understanding why it just put the 1st letter on of 4th item of my list. I am looking to generate many divs to each individual list on my nested list.

```
def generate_concept_HTML(concept_title, concept_heading, concept_description):
    html_title ='''
<div class="title">
     <h2 id="l-3">
     ''' + concept_title
    html_text_1 = '''
    </h2>
    <div class="concept">
        <div class="concept-title">
        ''' + concept_heading
    html_text_2 = '''
        </div>
        <div class="concept-description">
        ''' + concept_description
    html_text_3 = '''
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''
    full_html_text =html_title + html_text_1 + html_text_2 + html_text_3
    return full_html_text


my_titles_and_descriptions = [['Python','What is a Variable in Python?', 'Variables are nothing but reserved memory locations to store values.'],
                                ['Variable and different ways to assign values', 'We can assign the value 2 to the variable my_variable by writing code like this: my_variable = 2'],
                                ['Function also called a Procedure', 'A function is a block of organized, reusable code that is used to perform a single, related action. Functions are made by starting a line of code with the keyword def and then giving a function name followed by the function parameters in parentheses. parameters are what go inside the parentheses. Parameters are variables use in the function definitions that is a "handle" that allows the code in the fiction to access the arguments for a particular These parameters will eventually be replaced by actual values when the function is used (called).'],
                                ['How do functions help to avoid repetition?', 'Functions are tools that programmers can create and reuse forever! Once you\'ve defined a function once, you never have to define it again.'] ]


def get_title(concept):
    start_location = concept[0]
    title = start_location
    return title

def get_heading(concept):
    start_location = concept[1][0]
    title = start_location
    return title

def get_description(concept):
    start_location = concept[1][1]
    description = start_location
    return description

def make_HTML(page):
    concept_title = page[0][0]
    concept_heading = page[0][1]
    concept_description = page[0][2]
    page = generate_concept_HTML(concept_title, concept_heading, concept_description)
    return page


def make_HTML_for_many_items(list_of_items):
    HTML_start = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Stage 2 submission. -->
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Javi's Important Notions</title>
    </head>'''
    HTML_end = '''
    </body>
</html>'''
    for html in list_of_items:
        page_HTML = make_HTML(html)
        html_page = HTML_start + page_HTML + HTML_end
    return html_page

print make_HTML_for_many_items(my_titles_and_descriptions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is in `make_HTML()` function. The `page` argument to it (according to your code) is a 1D list of strings, but you are trying to access it as if it were a 2D list, as-

```
def make_HTML(page):
    concept_title = page[0][0]
    concept_heading = page[0][1]
    concept_description = page[0][2]
```

So this is only taking the first character for title, only the second character for heading, etc. This must be what is causing your issue.

If what you need is the complete string, access the `page` argument as if it were a 1D list, Example -

```
def make_HTML(page):
    concept_title = page[0]
    concept_heading = page[1]
    concept_description = page[2]
```

---

Another issue as asked in the comments -

> i was wondering why it just display the 4 line on my nested list. I want it to repeat each line not just the last list
>
> It works great but I getting multiple HTML_start = and HTML_end = and I just need those on the top and bottom of the HTML page. How do I go about making the just print once in the top and bottom of the page_HTML from the loop?

The issue occurs because you are overwriting the `html_page` variable each time, so it only contains the html_page from the last list. That happens in line -

```
html_page = HTML_start + page_HTML + HTML_end
```

You may want to store the html start in a html_page first and then append each page to `html_page` and then return `html_page + html_end`. Example -

```
def make_HTML_for_many_items(list_of_items):
    HTML_start = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Stage 2 submission. -->
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Javi's Important Notions</title>
    </head>'''
    HTML_end = '''
    </body>
</html>'''
    html_page = HTML_start
    for html in list_of_items:
        page_HTML = make_HTML(html)
        html_page += page_HTML
    return html_page + HTML_end

print make_HTML_for_many_items(my_tittles_and_descriptions)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Anand. I get a index out of range on        concept_description = page[2]

Comment: I know why because of my list don't have an index on 2. Thanks!

Comment: i was wondering why it just display the 4 line on my nested list. I want it to repeat each line not just the last list.

Comment: Added explanation for that in answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explenation. It works great but I getting multiple  HTML_start = and HTML_end = and I just need those on the top and bottom of the HTML page. How do I go about making the just print once in the top and bottom of the page_HTML from the loop?